# Reconstructing binary tree from inorder and preorder traversals

Tags: java, binary-tree, traversal, inorder

I have written the following code for constructing a tree from its inorder and preorder traversals. It looks correct to me but the final tree it results in does not have the same inorder output as the one it was built from. Can anyone help me find the flaw in this function?

```
public btree makeTree(int[] preorder, int[] inorder,  int left,int right)
{
    if(left > right)
        return null;

    if(preIndex >= preorder.length)
        return null;

    btree tree = new btree(preorder[preIndex]);
    preIndex++;

    int i=0;
    for(i=left; i<= right;i++)
    {
        if(inorder[i]==tree.value)
            break;

    }


        tree.left = makeTree(preorder, inorder,left, i-1);
        tree.right = makeTree(preorder, inorder,i+1, right );

    return tree;

}
```

Note: preIndex is a static declared outside the function.

Comment: Ehm.. what exactly is this good for? :)

Comment: Nothing. It's an interesting question that I am trying to answer. No harm in that I suppose.

Comment: @Javaguru - [academic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558032/prove-that-binary-trees-with-the-same-inorder-and-preorder-traversals-are-identic) at first sight - but on the other hand, one could serialize a binary tree by just storing the results of inorder and preorder traversals.

Comment: Oh yes, that is true. Useful insight.

Comment: @Sid, there is one more related question on SO: [Construct a tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184949/construct-a-tree) - from inorder and *postorder* traversals. Different input but maybe interesting...

Comment: Obviously, in only works if all the values are different

Comment: Could you run it with the simple tree `inorder[]={2,1,3}` and `preorder[]={1,2,3}` and give the `inorder[]` of the constructed tree? Or, if the algorithm for this simple tree works, another example with the most simple input tree that shows the problem!? - and please show the left/right values for the first call of makeTree.

Comment: It seems to work fine for the simplest trees. I just don't see where it is failing for larger inputs. I have tried your example and many others and it's working fine for the simple tree.

Comment: in = {1,3,2,5};
 pre = {2,1,5,3};

For this case, the inorder traversal of the new tree gives {1,5,2,3} whereas the preorder is still fine.

Comment: Am I wrong, or do you also need to specify the root-node in order to reconstruct a tree uniquely from any kind of traversal? So, without specifying the root node, the only possibility for which the result would be correct is a totally balanced tree, not?

Comment: Since we have both the preorder and inorder traversals, it is sufficient to construct the tree. The root node is simply the first node in the preorder tarversal. The idea is that once you find the node in the inorder array we can partition the array here and the left and right subtrees are also in inorder so we can recursively build the tree.

Comment: the root node is the first of preorder

Comment: I think that in your example, in = {1,3,2,5} and pre = {2,1,5,3} cannot have been produced from the same tree: the root is 2 and there should be 1 and 3 at its left and 5 at its right. So 1 should be followed by 3 in pre.

Comment: That is correct. My example was wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
in = {1,3,2,5}; pre = {2,1,5,3};
```

I've some difficulties constructing the tree 'by hand'. `pre` shows that `2` must be the root, `in` shows that {1,3} are nodes of the left subtree, `{5}` is the right subtree:

```
      2
     / \
    /   \
  {1,3} {5}
```

But knowing this, `3` can't be the last element in `pre` because it is clearly an element of the left subtree *and* we have a right subtree. Valid preorder traversals for these trees are `{2,1,3,5}` or `{2,3,1,5}`. But `{2,1,5,3}` is impossible.

Maybe the bug is not in this method but in your algorithm to create inorder and preorder traversals. Or, could it be, that you chose the values for `in[]` and `pre[]` randomly?

Comment: Crap! That is right I think. I cannot believe I have wasted so much time thinking I have misunderstood recursion when I was right all along. Thanks.