# Construct a (non-binary) tree from pre-order and post-order traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree

The tree I am going to be using consists of nodes with a left child and a right sibling. Besides the left child, siblings will not be connected to the parent node.

I need to reconstruct the tree from pre-order list and post-order list.

Example - The first line below is the pre-order, the second is the post-order.

```
QRUVSTWXZY 
UVRSWZXYTQ
```

The tree would look like this:

```
      Q
   /  |  \
  R   S   T
 / \    / | \
U   V  W  X  Y
          |
          Z
```

I have a vague idea about how I can go through those two lists and construct a tree, but my logic is keep bumping into walls.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm or method that could go through two lists and find a structure?

Comment: This might help - [reconstructing a tree from its preorder and postorder lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1136999)

Comment: @Dukeling yes I have looked at that. does not really. thank you for editing so nicely tho :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is compare both the lists,we use a simple idea that a parent node will always be before its child in pre order and in post order its the inverse.
step1 
    if first element in pre-order is equal to the last element of post order its the root node(parent node) of the left out list and remove it from both lists.
Qruvstwxzy-->ruvstwxzy
uvrswzxytQ-->uvrswzxyt
step2
now compare both lists(new) the element in first position is a immediate child of the previously removed node now seperate the string ass a substring till the same element occurs in the post order list. now do the same with now leftout strings iteratively
Ruvstwxzy--> Ruv S Twxzy 
uvRswzxyt--> uvR S wzxyT
step3 
if in this iteration we are getting a string with one element then its a leaf node and the immediate child to the parent noed of this whole string.

By doing this iteratively we will get the exact tree which you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 1: If and only if node A appears before node B in the pre-order, and after node B in the post-order, node A is an ancestor of node B.

Based on this, for any two nodes, we can determine whether one is an ancestor of the other or not.

Using this, we first place the root R (the firstmost node in the preorder). Then we place the first child A1 of the root (the secondmost node in the preorder). Now using theorem 1, we can determine which other nodes are somewhere below A1. All those nodes will appear after A1 in the pre-order, and before A1 in the post-order. Among the other nodes (which are not below A1), the first one to appear in the pre-order, is also a direct child of R. Let's call it A2. We can again find out which other nodes are somewhere below A2. Then place A3. And so on.

This way, we've rebuilt the tree down to the first level (A1, A2, A3,...An), and we know which nodes are somewhere below A1, which nodes are somewhere below A2, and so on. Now we can follow the above process recursively for each of A1, A2, etc and we shall have the tree!