# recursively building trees

Tags: tree

I've recently started haskell and I tried to create a tree.

I'm given the definitions as:

```
import Data.Char (toLower, toUpper)
import Data.Tree (Tree(Node))
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Set (Set, empty, insert)

data Mt = Leaf Integer | Branch Integer Integer Mt deriving Show

buildTree  :: a −> b −> Mt
```

I feel myself totally lost. Can anyone help me to write that function?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136999/reconstructing-a-tree-from-its-preorder-and-postorder-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import qualified Data.List as L
data Mt = Null | Node Integer [Mt] deriving Show


buildTree _ [] = Null
buildTree [] _ = Null
buildTree prelist postlist = 
  let n = head prelist 
      restofnodespre = tail prelist 
      restofnodespost = init postlist 
      subtrees = maketree restofnodespre restofnodespost
      treelist = map (\(pr, ps) -> buildTree pr ps) subtrees
  in
      Node n treelist



maketree _ [] = []
maketree [] _ = []
maketree pre post = 
  let s = head pre 
      rest = takeWhile (/=s) post 
      newpost = rest ++ [s]
      newpre = L.intersect pre newpost 
      remainingpre = pre L.\\ newpre
      remainingpost = post L.\\ newpost
  in
      (newpre , newpost): (maketree remainingpre remainingpost)
```