# Java reconstruction tree from postorder and preorder

Tags: java

Hy, 
i have some troubles i want to reconstructe tree with two travelsar (postorder and preoorder). I saw on netbeans at least 5 hours and i cant solve problem with my this code. If anyone saw what i make wrong or give me other reconstruction. I will be vary grateful

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ReConstructBTree {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String[] pre = "I Q J H L E M V O T S B R G Y Z K C A & F P N U D W X".split("\\s");
  String[] post = "H E M L J V Q S G Y R Z B T C P U D N F W & X A K O I".split("\\s");

  List preList = Arrays.asList(pre);
  List postList = Arrays.asList(post);

  BTree tree = reBuildTree(preList, postList);

  tree.inOrder(tree); //print in-order
  System.out.println();
  tree.postOrder(tree);//print post order to re-check
  System.out.println();
  tree.preOrder(tree);//print pre order to re-check
 }

 private static BTree reBuildTree(List preList, List postList) {
  BTree tree = null;

  if(preList.size() != 0 && postList.size() != 0) {
   tree = new BTree();
   String val = preList.get(0);
   tree.val = val;

   if(preList.size() > 1 && postList.size() > 1) {
    int postOrderPos = postList.indexOf(preList.get(1));
    int preOrderPos = preList.indexOf(postList.get(postList.size()-2));

    //find the two sub set of the list from pre-order
    List leftPreOrder = preList.subList(1, preOrderPos);
    List rightPreOrder = preList.subList(preOrderPos, preList.size());

    //find the two sub set of the list from post-order
    List leftPostOrder = postList.subList(0, postOrderPos+1);
    List rightPostOrder = postList.subList(postOrderPos+1, postList.size()-1);

    tree.left = reBuildTree(leftPreOrder, leftPostOrder);
    tree.right = reBuildTree(rightPreOrder, rightPostOrder);
   }
  }

  return tree;
 }

 static class BTree {
  String val;
  BTree left;
  BTree right;

  void inOrder(BTree tree) {
   if(tree.left != null)
    inOrder(tree.left);
   System.out.print(tree.val+" ");
   if(tree.right != null)
    inOrder(tree.right);
  }

  void preOrder(BTree tree) {
   System.out.print(tree.val+" ");
   if(tree.left != null)
    preOrder(tree.left);
   if(tree.right != null)
    preOrder(tree.right);
  }

  void postOrder(BTree tree) {
   if(tree.left != null)
    postOrder(tree.left);
   if(tree.right != null)
    postOrder(tree.right);
   System.out.print(tree.val+" ");
  }

 }
}
```

This code can only reconstruction 2 depth or low..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of tree are you constructing ?? General Binary Tree reconstruction uniquely is **not possible** from just pre-order and post-order traversal. ( Refer here for [explanation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/if-you-are-given-two-traversal-sequences-can-you-construct-the-binary-tree/) and [more discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136999/reconstructing-a-tree-from-its-preorder-and-postorder-lists) )