# how many binary trees are possible that satisfies a given preorder and postorder traversal?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

For example

preorder->0,1,2

postorder->2,1,0

```
      0
     /
    1
   /
  2

      0
     /
    1
     \
      2

      0
       \
        1
       /   
      2

      0
       \
        1
         \
          2
```

These are the 4 binary trees possible for above case.How many trees are possible in general for any preorder and postorder traversals?

Comment: How does this relate to programming? If you feel it does, could you provide your code, and indicate what the issue is with it? Otherwise this seems a question that might be more suitable for [maths.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You already know that with two nodes there would be two possible trees, and with three nodes there are four possible trees. If you do the above exercise with four nodes, you'll likely discover the progression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to your question:

- For given postorder and preorder traversals of a *binary* tree, you can only find a single tree. (note the emphasis on binary! I only allow the root to have degree 2)
  A proof sketch is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136999/reconstructing-a-tree-from-its-preorder-and-postorder-lists#2693499), where you can also find a reconstruction algorithm.
- If your tree is allowed to have inner nodes of degree 2, i.e. nodes with only one child, then you can place it either on the left or on the right side, the corresponding subtree's position in the pre- and postorder traversal won't change. So if you have `k` such nodes, you have `2^k` equivalent trees